# webpack-encore-bundle Unknown "encore_entry_script_tags" function

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, webpack-encore

Issue is with symfony 4, php 7.3.7.

I have ran `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` and added the default `webpack.config.js` as recommend in the documentation.

When I add `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}` to my `base.html.twig` I get an error saying that the function is unknown.

Google is leading me nowhere and the documentation says that it is good to go right out of the box if you have symfony flex, which I do.

I tried adding a `webpack_encore.yaml` to `config/packages` but it threw an error saying that there is no package to build with this configuration.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: try run in your terminal (sure in the project folder): `yarn encore dev` #or npm encore dev, if you use npm (<-- you need run this once after any css, js update... may need run also after the install)

Comment: Did you activate the bundle in your `config/bundles.php`?

Answer (score 3):

please be sure your config/bundles.php has this line.

```
return [
    ...
    Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    ...
];
```

also check 'config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml' is exist. Here is default config.

```
webpack_encore:    
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build'
```